# Excel Circular Reference

Tags: excel, ms-office, circular-reference

I have a cell that is taking the number of days in the month and displaying how many days are left in the month.  I needed it to display "0" is the number is Negative, and display to total days of the month if the number is greater than the amount of days in a month.  The formula I have works, only I am getting a circular reference error on it and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(NOW(),EOMONTH(K50,0),Table1[Date])<0,"0",IF(NETWORKDAYS(NOW(),EOMONTH(K50,0),Table1[Date])>N51,N51,NETWORKDAYS(NOW(),EOMONTH(K50,0),Table1[Date])))
```

The formula is placed in cell N52

```
Days in month    20
Days Remaining   20  //Displays different based on value <> 0 or > 20
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What are in K50 and N51 and table1[date], are they formulas?  Do they refer back to N52?

Comment: FWIW: after you figure out why the circular reference, which has nothing to do with the formula you posted, so must reside with other formulas on the sheet, you can shorten this to `=MAX(0,IF(NETWORKDAYS(NOW(),EOMONTH(K50,0),Table1[Date])>N51,N51,NETWORKDAYS(NOW(),EOMONTH(K50,0),Table1[Date])))`

Comment: My instinct was to do `MAX(MIN(x,0),30)` to get some number between 0 and 30.  Final looks like this: `=MAX(MIN(NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(),EOMONTH(D7,0)), E7),0)` where D7 contains the first date of the month and E7 contains the number of days in the month

Comment: K50 and N51 Just contain a date (formatted MMMM) and the EOMONTH formula for that date to find the total number of working days.  Neither refer back to N52

Comment: @CodeJockey your code worked and is much cleaner than mine.  Still getting the circular reference though.  The only cells that are referring to that cell is referring back to N52 is a cell totalling other cells doing the same function together (to total remaining days for a quarter) together (S52) which is not referencing itself.

Comment: Start with all the cells to which this formula refers, then go to the cells to which they refer and so on till you dead end with actual entered data.  Some way, some how you are creating a circle.  It may be 4 or more formula in the circle.

Comment: There is a circular reference tool in the Formula tab that might be of assistance also.

Comment: @CodeJockey I know the reference tool.  The circular reference under error checking is greyed out.  That was my first go-to.  I also traced the dependencies and was unable to find anything.  I may just have the users deal with the error and circle back to it on the next round of bug fixes.